# Longest consecutive subsequence in dates array

Tags: java, android, date, jodatime

Hi I have an `Arraylist` containing dates in increasing order. Dates are of this format `yyyy-MM-dd`. Now I want to find out longest consecutive subsequence in that `Arraylist`. I have checked for solutions online but they are related to int arrays and I want to find out for dates array.
Code for int array:

```
// Returns length of the longest contiguous subarray
int findLength(int arr[], int n)
{
int max_len = 1;  // Initialize result
for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
{
    // Initialize min and max for all subarrays starting with i
    int mn = arr[i], mx = arr[i];

    // Consider all subarrays starting with i and ending with j
    for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
    {
        // Update min and max in this subarray if needed
        mn = min(mn, arr[j]);
        mx = max(mx, arr[j]);

        // If current subarray has all contiguous elements
        if ((mx - mn) == j-i)
            max_len = max(max_len, mx-mn+1);
    }
}
return max_len;  // Return result
}

// Utility functions to find minimum and maximum of
// two elements
int min(int x, int y) { return (x < y)? x : y; }
int max(int x, int y) { return (x > y)? x : y; }
```

Comment: The reason it's not straightforward to modify is that this method is checking if "current subarray has all contiguous elements" and dates are not "contiguous elements". You can treat Dates as "days of the year" or something else which will make them potentially contiguous elements, but this is not straightforward.

Comment: Yes i made changes to this code but its working for one month only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using this code and if anyone is facing same problem they can use this code:

```
private int getBest(){
    //Getting dates
    ArrayList<Date> successDates = new ArrayList<>();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    for(int i=0; i<successDays.size(); i++){
        try {
            successDates.add(sdf.parse(successDays.get(i)));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    int max_len = 1;
    for(int i=0; i<successDates.size(); i++){
        Date mn = successDates.get(i);
        Date mx = successDates.get(i);
        for(int j=i+1; j<successDates.size(); j++){
            if(mn.compareTo(successDates.get(j))>0){
                mn = successDates.get(j);
            }
            if(mx.compareTo(successDates.get(j))<0){
                mx = successDates.get(j);
            }
            if(getDaysBetweenDates(mn, mx) == j-i){
                if(max_len < getDaysBetweenDates(mn, mx)+1){
                    max_len = getDaysBetweenDates(mn, mx) + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return max_len;
}

private int getDaysBetweenDates(Date min, Date max){
    Calendar mn = Calendar.getInstance();
    mn.setTime(min);

    Calendar mx = Calendar.getInstance();
    mx.setTime(max);

    long msDiff = mx.getTimeInMillis() - mn.getTimeInMillis();
    return (int)TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(msDiff);
}
```

Comment: FYI, the old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between ( 
    LocalDate.parse( previousString ) , 
    LocalDate.parse( currentString )
)
```

## String != date

> I have an Arraylist containing dates in increasing order. Dates are of this format yyyy-MM-dd.

That means you have a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of String objects, not dates. The main challenge here is to get date objects so you can calculate days in between them.

## java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy classes (`Date`, `Calendar`, etc.).

Your input strings happen to comply with standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. And the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes happen to use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a [formatting pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html?is-external=true).

```
List<String> inputs = new ArrayList<> ();
inputs.add ( "2016-01-23" );
inputs.add ( "2016-01-25" );
inputs.add ( "2016-02-22" ); // End of longest period between dates.
inputs.add ( "2016-02-25" );
inputs.add ( "2016-02-28" );
```

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

The strategy of this example code is to calculate the days between each `LocalDate` (parsed from each incoming String) and the previous `LocalDate`. If longer than the longest seen so far, forget the old longest and remember the current loop’s data.

```
LocalDate longestStart = null;
LocalDate longestStop = null;
LocalDate previousDate = null;
long longestInDays = 0;
```

The [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) has handy methods such as calculating elapsed days.

```
for ( String input : inputs ) {
    LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.parse ( input );
    if ( null == previousDate ) {  // First loop.
        previousDate = currentDate;
        continue;  // Skip the rest of this first loop.
    }
    long currentDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between ( previousDate , currentDate );
    if ( currentDays > longestInDays ) {
        // If the current loop exceeds previous longest, remember this one as longest.
        longestInDays = currentDays;
        longestStart = previousDate;
        longestStop = currentDate;
    }
    // Prepare for next loop.
    previousDate = currentDate;
}
```

Dump results to console.

```
System.out.println ( "Longest period has days: " + longestInDays + " = " + longestStart + "/" + longestStop );
```

> Longest period has days: 28 = 2016-01-25/2016-02-22

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/RcaE4Q).

Comment: Thanks @Basil Bourque